# 502 proxy error apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, proxy, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

Below is my virtual host conf for https proxy

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin kirthan@openjuice.in
    ServerName example.openjuice.co

    ProxyRequests off
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/cert/certs/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/cert/certs/apache.key

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
        ProxyPass https://localhost:3006/
        ProxyPassReverse https://example.openjuice.co:3006/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

But i am getting below error

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>
> The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server

Please help me on this

Comment: Do you have any Apache log ? Did you tired : `ProxyPass https://localhost:3006/ Keepalive=On` ?

Comment: Hi
It got worked by adding below line to above conf
SSLProxyEngine on

SSLProxyVerify none

SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off

SSLProxyCheckPeerName off

SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

Answer (score 2):

***It worked for me Add below to above conf***

```
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none 
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off    
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off    
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
```

Comment: could you set your answer as valid (the check button under the vote button) ? thanks

Comment: This works!
@kirthan shetty, please accept the answer.

Comment: Please note that disabling the `SSLProxyCheck*` bypasses many security benefits of SSL/TLS. You may need to use it in some situations, but you should be aware of the security risks and don't just use this blindly to fix the error without knowing what they do.